# Google Drive file sharing popup in GWT application

Tags: java, gwt, google-drive-api, google-docs

Is there a simple way to integrate the sharing/permissions popup dialogbox for Google Drive files into a GWT+GAE (Java) application?

Answer (score 1):

Google APIs have a GWT client supports authorization and authentication. I'd suggest you to take a look at it. They don't have a Drive sample but it's similar to the flow they've implemented for other APIs. Take a look at the G+ sample: https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/source/browse/trunk/apis/samples/plus/com/google/api/gwt/samples/plus/client/PlusEntryPoint.java

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I am not sure if the link you provided has anything to do with sharing (i.e., giving permission to access) files with other users. This is more about authentication, which is something I have already taken care of using the appropriate OAuth 2.0 implementation for my application. Please correct me if I am mistaken. Thanks.

Comment: Ah sorry, you are asking for a native GWT "share" widget for Drive. I don't think there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it here:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/drive/manage-sharing#launching_the_google_drive_sharing_dialog_in_your_app

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    init = function() {
        s = new gapi.drive.share.ShareClient('<YOUR_APP_ID>');
        s.setItemIds(["<FILE_ID>"]);
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        gapi.load('drive-share', init);
    }
</script>

<button onclick="s.showSettingsDialog()">Share</button>
```

However since it appears to only be available in Javascript, you will have to use GWT Native functions [JSNI](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html):

```
public static native void alert(String msg) /*-{
  $wnd.alert(msg);
}-*/;
```